# gems for working with files

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Which most popular/usable gems for working with files are? Uploading/Downloading. I am not meaning working with pictures. For example I need attach some Word and Pdf document to my model, so user can download these files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Paperclip is a great gem for uploading files.  You can pair it with the aws-s3 gem if you want to store your uploads on s3.  I use it for pictures, binary files, and pdfs.  You don't need a gem for downloads most likely.

Answer (score 0):

[carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) and [dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly) are worth mentioning too.